# Why is this statement true: $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ iff $\gcd(n-a,n) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory

I know this has to do with Euclidean division, I just can't prove the => direction.
Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Assume some number divides both n-a and a, what else must it divide?

Answer (score 4):

Every common divisor $d$ of $a$ and $n$ is also a common divisor of $n - a$ and $a$. Conversely, every common divisor $d$ of $n - a$ and $a$ is also a common divisor of $n - a + a = n$ and $a$. Therefore the *greatest* common divisor of $a$ and $n$ is the same as the *greatest* common divisor of $n - a$ and $a$.

So, in general, $\gcd(a,n) = \gcd(n-a,n)$.

Comment: I know I always used to tell my students that whenever they saw $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, they should immediately think $xa + yb = 1$. Seeing the other answers all using Bézout, I wonder if I was right in doing so.

Comment: Much cleaner with better logic than simply running to a theorem. +1

Comment: Quite some are able to prove this by Bézouts lemma, but are they all capable to prove the lemma itself? I have my doubts about that.

Answer (score 1):

By [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) we have

$$\gcd(a,n)=1\iff \exists \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb Z\;|\; \alpha a+\beta n=1=(\alpha+\beta)a+\beta(n-a)=1\\\iff\gcd(n-a,a)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $\, d\mid n\ $ then $\ d\mid \color{#0a0}{n-a}\iff d\mid \color{#c00}a.\ $ Thus $\ \color{#0a0}{n-a},n\ $ and $\ \color{#c00}a,n\ $ have the same set $S$ of common divisors $\,d,\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $\,(= \max S).$

**Alternatively**, note that the map $\ (a,n)\mapsto (n-a,n)\ $ is *linear* with determinant $\,\Delta = \color{}{-1}.\ $ Therefore, by the proof below$\ \gcd(a,n) = \gcd(n-a,n).$

---

**Theorem**  $\ $ If $\rm\,(x,y)\overset{A}\mapsto (X,Y)\,$ is linear then $\: \rm\gcd(x,y)\mid \gcd(X,Y)\mid \Delta \gcd(x,y),\,\ \Delta = \det A$

**Proof** $\ $ Inverting the linear map $\rm\,A\,$ by [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) (multiplying by the adjugate) yields

$$\rm \begin{eqnarray} a\ x\, +\, b\ y &=&\rm X\\ \\ \rm c\ x\, +\, d\ y &\ =\ &\rm Y\end{eqnarray}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad \begin{array} \rm\Delta\ x\ \ \ =\ \ \ \rm d\ X\, -\, b\ Y \\\\ \rm\Delta\ y\ =\ \rm -c\ X\, +\, a\ Y \end{array}\ ,\quad\ \Delta\ =\ ad-bc\qquad $$

Hence, by RHS system, $\rm\ n\ |\ X,Y\ \Rightarrow\ n\ |\ \Delta\:x,\:\Delta\:y\ \Rightarrow\ n\ |\ gcd(\Delta\:x,\Delta\:y)\ =\ \Delta\ gcd(x,y)\:.$
In particular $\rm\ n = \gcd(X,Y) \mid \Delta\, \gcd(x,y).\ $

Further, by LHS system $\rm\,n\mid x,y\ \Rightarrow\ n\mid X,Y\ \Rightarrow\ n\mid\gcd(X,Y).$
In particular $\rm\ n = gcd(x,y)\mid \gcd(X,Y).\ \ \ $  **QED**

Comment: No Bézout, so +1.

Comment: Using this to prove Bézout is okay. But the other way around (proving this by using Bézout) displeases me.

Comment: @drhab I added another way that doesn't use Bezout.

Comment: Nice! And completely new to me. A pity that I run out of upvotes to provide :)

Answer (score 0):

Proof by [Zout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity):

If $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then there exists $x$ and $y$ for them $ax+ny=1$, hence $a(x+y)+(n-a)y=1$ and then $\gcd(n-a,a)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Use the property $gcd(a,b)=1 \Leftrightarrow$ there exist $m,n$ such that $ma+nb=1$

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose that $gcd(a,n)=1$. Then there exist $l,k$ such that $la+kn=1 \Leftrightarrow kn-ka+ka+la=1\Leftrightarrow k(n-a)+(k+l)a=1$. So $gcd(n-a,a)=1.$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $gcd(n-a,a)=1$. Then there exist $l,k$ such that  $l(n-a)+ka=1 \Leftrightarrow  ln+(k-l)a =1$. Thus $gcd(a,n)=1$.